# Placing a button in the center of a div

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm looking to place a button in the center of a `<div>`. I want this button to be placed in the middle of the two colors. I screenshotted a picture of how I would like it to look but I can't seem to figure out how to do it.

[image: Screenshot of website with desired button]

Here is my HTML code:

```
<div id="enter">
         <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12" id="dcPicture">
                <h1 id="welcome" data-uk-scrollspy="{cls:'uk-animation-fade', delay:300, repeat:true}">
                    WELCOME TO DURACOM
                </h1>
            </div>
        <div class="wrap">
            <div class="fleft" data-uk-scrollspy="{cls:'uk-animation-slide-left'}">
                <h1 id="residential">Residential</h1>
                <img class="home" src="home.png" data-uk-scrollspy="{cls:'uk-animation-slide-bottom', delay: 500}">
            </div>
        <div class="fright" data-uk-scrollspy="{cls:'uk-animation-slide-right'}">
                <h1 id="commercial">Commercial</h1>
                <img class="biz" src="commercial.png" data-uk-scrollspy="{cls:'uk-animation-slide-bottom', delay: 500}">
          </div> 
       </div>
```

And here is my CSS:

```
.wrap {
width: 100%;
overflow:auto;
padding-bottom: 50px;
}

.fleft {
    float:left; 
    width: 50%;
background: #012a6a;
    height: 600px;
}
#residential {
   font-family: "Segoe UI", Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
   font-size: 48px;
   font-weight: 100;
   color: white;
   text-align: center;
   padding-top: 10%;
}
.fright {
float: right;
    background: #117bc2;
    height: 600px;
    width: 50%;
}
#commercial {
    font-family: "Segoe UI", Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
    font-size: 48px;
    font-weight: 100;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 10%;
}
img.home {
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto
}
img.biz {
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code above has two images and you don't say which is supposed to be in the center, but have a look at this Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/pfeoda25/ which uses

```
position:relative
```

to achieve the effect.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can do it:

https://jsfiddle.net/6eq3v3LL/

This is the CSS I added:

```
.wrap {
  position: relative;
}

.button {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  bottom: 80px;
  color: #fff;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  padding: 5px 30px;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%);
  transform: translate(-50%);
}
```

I just style the button with a border for demo... change to however you desire.

Answer (score 0):

give to `.wrap` relative position:

```
.wrap{
   position: relative;
}
```

then create your button in `.wrap`:

```
<div class="wrap">
   <div class="fleft"></div>
   <div class="fright"></div>
   <button>balh balh</button>
</div>
```

after that, give this style to the button:

```
button{
   bottom: 50px;
   left: 50%;
}
```

do yourself other styles like width,opacity and ...